# How can i get the value from div class in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

how can i get the value "2017-03-11T04:50" from the below html using selenium webdriver.

```
<div class="game-date-time">
  <span data-date="2017-03-11T04:50Z" data-behavior="date_time">
  <span class="time game-time" data-dateformat="time1" data-showtimezone="true">10:20 AM IST</span>
  <span class="game-date" data-dateformat="date12">11 March 2017</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ravi, have you got chance to try the solution provided?

Answer (score 3):

Your div text does not provide value in the format as you mentioned `("2017-03-11T04:50")`

To just get the value you can use `xpath`. Then you can parse the string to eliminate "Z". (if that is what you are looking for)

```
//get the attribute value first.

String date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='game-date-time']/span[@data-behavior='date_time']")).getAttribute("data-date");

// parsing for'z'.

String parts[] = date.split("z");

// to get fist portion.

String dateParsed = parts[0]; //which should be "2017-03-11T04:50"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's may be late but recently I was attempting to get the values by div class name but I tried all solutions available but then I found following is currently works perfect if you want to select by class name which is a div class.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.class_name')
```

for this example it would be

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.game-date-time')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, I have used xpath to find the element you want and have called `getAttribute()` method to get the attribute value of the tag.

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='game-date-time']/span[@data-behavior='date_time']")).getAttribute("data-date");
```

.

```
String date = value.substring(0,value.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple get it by using below statement:

The `xpath` part gets the data string and removes `Z`, *all in single statement*.

```
String dateString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("substring-before(//div[@class='game-date-time']/span[@data-behavior='date_time']/@data-date,'Z')"));
System.out.println("Date string :"+dateString);
```

Online <kbd>[demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/7OYVFX6Ym)</kbd> for the xpath

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value by using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span")).getAttribute("data-date");
```

Here is the sample code for this[image]